# Wordpress/Woocommerce How to display subcategories on page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have code which display category name and category image, but i want to display only subcategories from parent Category.

http://scr.hu/2h3l/zx0db
i need to display all subcategories from upholstery

Any ideas ?

```
<div class="category row">
<?php $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '17,77')); ?>

    <?php foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : 
           $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id,'thumbnail_id', true );
           $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
    ?>

        <div class="category-item col-md-6"><a href="<?php echo $catTerm->slug; ?>"><?php if($wimage!=""):?><img src="<?php echo $wimage?>"><?php endif;?><span><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></span></a></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Woocommerce Product Category Page. Find the category upholstery, click on edit. And from the edit page, Set Display type to Subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

With-in your "foreach" loop, just check if current term has parent.

```
if($catTerm->parent > 0){
  //do what ever if this term has parent
}
```